Thumb nail slider using swiper

ERROR in ./src/App.js 27:16-24 export 'FreeMode' (imported as
'FreeMode') was not found in 'swiper' (possible exports: Swiper,
default)
ERROR in ./src/App.js 27:26-36 export 'Navigation' (imported as
'Navigation') was not found in 'swiper' (possible exports: Swiper,
default)
ERROR in ./src/App.js 27:38-44 export 'Thumbs' (imported as 'Thumbs')
was not found in 'swiper' (possible exports: Swiper, default)

webpack compiled with 3 errors and 1 warning
I am facing this issue in the App.js file
I am expecting this kind of output. kindly check the output in the youtube link given below.
https://youtu.be/YDj9kcNIGa8?si=f1xNPzD3UyO91j6W

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I want a to create thumb nail slider in react using swiper but iam getting these errors can u help me out?
